# Error getting main window kAXErrorServerNotFound - Cannot Find the Target Application

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest

My XCUITest will fail on one screen because of cannot Find the Target Application:

Could anyone please give some suggestion here? I don't understand how comes when first land on this screen the script can still locate the Application, but a few seconds later, it could not? thanks a lot!

------------  Here's the log -----------

```
t =    22.83s Tap Target Application 'com.ss.bbapp'
t =    22.83s     Wait for com.ss.bbapp to idle
t =    22.89s     Find the Target Application 'com.ss.bbapp'
t =    23.98s         Find the Target Application 'com.ss.bbapp' (retry 1)
t =    25.04s         Find the Target Application 'com.ss.bbapp' (retry 2)
t =    25.21s     Assertion Failure: SearchScreen.swift:219: Error getting main window kAXErrorServerNotFound
t =    25.25s Tear Down
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue ?